# modified $\sum{k{n \choose k}}$ closed form expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

There is probably something stupidly simple I'm missing, but I'm trying to find a closed form for:

$$
2\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} k \, {n \choose k}  \hspace{1cm} (n\textrm{ is odd})
$$

Anyone know how to do this?

I've figured out that since $n$ is odd,

$$
2+2\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}{n \choose k} = 2^n
$$

Thanks...

Comment: Should be at least legible now...is there something else wrong with it?

Comment: Note that $k \binom{n}{k} = n \binom{n-1}{k-1}$, and proceed.

Comment: Don't worry, now's fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a complete solution, using the equation in the above comments i.e. $k \binom{n}{k} = n \binom{n-1}{k-1}$, we get that if $n= 2m+1$, $$2\sum_{k=1}^{m} k \binom{2m+1}{k} = 2(2m+1) \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m}{k} = (2m+1) \left(\sum_{k=0}^{2m} \binom{2m}{k} - \binom{2m}{m} \right) = n \left(2^{n-1} - \binom{n-1}{(n-1)/2} \right)$$

Comment: I think the last expression can be simplified as $n{n-1\choose m}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd we have (where $j=\frac{n-1}{2}$):
\begin{eqnarray}
2^n &=& \binom{n}{0}+ \binom{n}{1} +\binom{n}{2} + \cdots +\binom{n}{n-2} +\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n} \\
 &=& \left \{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{n} \right \} +\left[ \left \{  \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{n-1}\right \} + \cdots + \left \{\binom{n}{j} + \binom{n}{j+1} \right \} \right]\\
 &=& 2+ 2\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} \binom{n}{k}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I think this was the equation that he already figured out, not the one that we were supposed to find. Also, some errors remain.

Comment: fixed the errors in his derivation (once it goes through peer review)